# SAP JCo Server ERROR: Session conflict. A new session could not be created within the current thread session

Tags: java, jco

Did anybody encounter this error thrown by SAP software, which is invoking a RFC call to a JCo Server?

> com.sap.conn.jco.ext.SessionException: (170) JCO_ERROR_CREATE_SESSION: Session conflict. A new session could not be created wit...

We are using JCo sapjco3-linuxx86_64-3.0.10 version.

Comment: I am wondering why people are so often using old, unpatched software, which is already several years old, and then complaining about an error without at least trying to test the scenario with using the latest patches first? [no, the downvote wasn't from me]

Comment: Thanks a lot !   SAP JCO Lib is not open for download as  maven repository,We could not get it easy , even  see some release note.

Comment: The SAP JCo is not free software. But it is available for all SAP customers and SAP partners without additional charge. So ask your in-house SAP administrator to download a copy for you. Otherwise, if you are not an SAP customer or SAP partner, I guess that you do not have a software license for using the SAP Java Connector.

Comment: Ok! We’ll  ask our sap admin. Thank you !

Comment: If my answer solved your question, I would be glad if you would mark it as “accepted”. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest JCo patch level (currently 3.0.18) and the error should not occur anymore.